# C - My greedy algorithm is not working CS50x

Tags: c, algorithm, cs50

I am doing cs50x and have run into a spot of trouble with my work. I am supposed to create an algorithm that will output the least amout of coins required to give back change. E.g 0.41 dollars will be 4 coins, a quarter (0.25), two dimes, (0.10) and a cent (0.01).For some reason this algorithm is not working (it is out putting the incorrect number of coins) and I cannot figure out why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int Coins;
float Owed;

int main(void)
{
    printf("How much is owed?\n");
    Owed = GetFloat();
    while (Owed < 0)
    {
        printf("A positive number please");
        Owed = GetFloat();
    }
    if (Owed >= 0.25)
    {
        while (Owed >=0.25)
        {
            Owed = Owed - 0.25;
            Coins++;
        }
    }

     if (Owed >= 0.1)
    {
        while (Owed >=0.1)
        {
            Owed = Owed - 0.1;
            Coins++;
        }

    }

       if (Owed >= 0.05)
    {
        while (Owed >=0.05)
        {
            Owed = Owed - 0.05;
            Coins++;
        }

    }

       if (Owed >= 0.01)
    {
        while (Owed >= 0.01)
        {
            Owed = Owed - 0.01;
            Coins++;
        }

    }
    printf("%d",Coins);
}
```

When i ran the code and used 0.41 as the amount owed, i got 3 coins when the answer is supposed to be 4:

[GreedyNotWorkTerminalPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaWNY.png)

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and how to step through the code line by line while monitoring the variables and their values.

Comment: Instead of looping on each coin value, why not use modulo arithmetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using numbers (0.1, 0.05, 0.01) that don't have exact representations as floats, in exactly the same way that 2/3 doesn't have an exact representation as a 4-digit decimal.  C will use the closest float value instead, so the errors are very tiny but that's enough to make your comparisons fail unexpectedly.

Imagine if a float was a 4-digit decimal, and you had 2/3 dollar coins:

1. Start with Owed = 2.0000
2. Owed >= 0.6667, so Owed-=0.6667.  Now Owed = 1.3333
3. 1.3333 >= 0.6667, so Owed-=0.6667.  Now Owed = 0.6666
4. Oops!  Owed = 0.6666, but that is NOT >= 0.6667

You can fix this by changing your comparisons to allow for a little rounding error.  Instead of saying `>=0.25`, `>=0.1`, and `>=0.01`, use `>=0.245`, `>=0.095`, and `>=0.005`

Usually, though, it's better to use a type that can exactly represent the values you want to use.  Instead of `float` dollars, use `int` cents.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `float`, you need notice that it's possible to lose accuracy in this kind of operations. Look at this: [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

I recommend you work with cents, using a `int` instead.

[Coliru example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9420e1b7b4d03f9)